# Multiple filters in dplyr function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I would like to make a dplyr function that is flexible enough to take multiple filters.

I can make a function that uses one filter:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(name = c("mike","tom","jerry"), 
                 age = c(7,8,9),
                 hair_color = c("brown", "black", "brown"),
                 town = c("NYC","NYC","SF"))

filter_fun <- function(df = df, filter_var_1, filter_1) {
     filter_var_1 <- enquo(filter_var_1)

     df %>%
       filter(UQ(filter_var_1) == filter_1) 
}
test <- filter_fun(filter_var_1 = town, filter_1 = "NYC")
```

This code works.

However, I would like this to be flexible for multiple filters. I read through https://rpubs.com/hadley/dplyr-programming for advice which gave me the impression I need to use `!!!` and `...` but I'm not sure how that would work with multiple filter conditions. For example,

```
filter_fun <- function(df = df, filters = ..., conditions = ...) {
   filters <- quos(filters)
   conditions <- quos(conditions)
   df %>%
     filter(!!!filters == !!!conditions) -> eff
   return(eff)
}

nanna <- filter_fun(filters = c(hair_color,town), 
                    conditions = c("brown", "NYC"))
```

But this does not work. Error: `Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : 
  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?`

Once that is solved, I would also like to be able to change the sign of the filter. For example,

```
filter_fun <- function(df = df, 
                       filters = ..., 
                       conditions = ..., 
                       signs = ...) {
  filters <- quos(filters)
  conditions <- quos(conditions)
  types <- quos(signs)
  df %>%
     filter(!!!filters !!!signs !!!conditions) -> eff
  return(eff)
}

nanna <- filter_fun(filters = c(hair_color,town,age), 
                    conditions = c("brown", "NYC", 8), 
                    signs = c("==", "==", "<"))
```

That won't work...

Thanks!

Comment: The more "usual" way to do this would be to pass the expressions as parameters as filter itself does: `filter(hair=="brown", town=="NYC", age < 8)`. Is there a reason you want to break all these expressions apart?

Comment: I am trying to write a code that is usable by non-R users or at least beginners. Next step would be to put it in Shiny app. This question is the minimum needed for my purpose, but this filter fits within a larger function call. And I'm curious about the answer :)

Comment: Well shiny is always going to return things as strings rather than symbols. A solution to the problem you describe here won't work with shiny.

Comment: OK, thanks. I am still curious how to make this work. If the approach is wrong, I'd be curious to know of a better approach for a flexible filter function.